# Parameter lost when passed from view to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Dear All,

I'm not sure why, but the value "relevant_home->Home_name" I select in the view is somehow lost after I click the submit, as the data dump returns null. Any ideas?

Route:

```
Route::post('/analysis/output', array(

'as'        =>  'analysis-output',
'uses'      =>  'AnalysisController@postAnalysis'
));
```

View:

```
@extends('layout.main')



@section('content')
    <form action="{{URL::route('analysis-output')}}" method="post">
            <select>
                @foreach($relevant_homes as $relevant_home)
                    <option value="{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}">{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Analyse'>
        {{ Form::token() }}
    </form>
@stop
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class AnalysisController extends BaseController {

public function postAnalysis(){

        echo $relevant_home = Input::get('relevant_homes');
        dd($relevant_home); 

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `<select>` tag has no name?

Comment: I have found a lot of times I have forgotten to do $relevant_homes->get() and then it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You havent give your `select` a name. Try this in your view:

```
 @extends('layout.main')



 @section('content')
     <form action="{{URL::route('analysis')}}" method="post">
             <select name="relevant_homes">
                 @foreach($relevant_homes as $relevant_home)
                     <option value="{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}">{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}</option>
                 @endforeach
             </select>
         <input type='submit' value='Analyse'>
         {{ Form::token() }}
     </form>
 @stop
```

Comment: try also updating the action URL (reflected above)

Comment: Mmm why would changing the url help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'analysis-output')) }}
    <select name='relevant_homes' id='relevant_homes'>
        @foreach($relevant_homes as $relevant_home)
            <option value="{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}">{{$relevant_home->Home_name}}</option> 
        @endforeach
    </select>
    {{ Form::submit('Analyse') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If that isn't working is the option field actually got anything in it?